# Blacklist [v6], [v7] and [v8] or make them synonyms of [6], [7] and [8]

Tags: feature-request

In recent days I have seen them used on couple of questions. Like a wave. Most recently [this one](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/94963/revisions) But we already have numerical tags for versions. So could you please blacklist these tags or make them synonyms of the proper ones?

Comment: simply remove the tag from the question, it tagged only one question, it will deleted automatically within 24 hrs.

Comment: not related but check this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204028/how-do-i-flag-a-tag-if-it-is-not-constructive

Comment: @Bala been there, seen that :) But this time it was not the case, as these did not have any tags. Anyway, it suggests to take issue to meta and I just did :P

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure there's a problem here really.

The tags [v6](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/v6) and [v8](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/v8) don't exist, so we couldn't synonymise them even if we wanted to (well, short of creating them first, but that would be counter-intuitive). [v7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/v7) has zero questions related to it, so will be deleted by the midnight scripts.

If a pattern emerges, and those tags keep popping up, then absolutely we'll get some synonyms added. I just don't think a couple of questions in a short space of time warrants adding synonyms.

Blacklisting probably won't be an option either way, as that facility is only used in extreme cases.

Comment: Blacklisting a tag is possible even when the tag doesn't exist; in fact, the code for blacklisting a tag uses regular expressions to match one or more tags. It's not something moderators can do, though; only a Community Coordinator can.

Comment: Thanks @kiamlaluno, since it's regex based that makes sense. I guess a blacklist that didn't allow you to exclude soon-to-be-created tags would be pretty useless, thinking about it

Comment: That is what I see on http://drupal.stackexchange.com/admin/blacklist: ^drupal-?\d+.*$. I take blacklisting is more powerful since it is used from a Community Coordinator when it is really strictly necessary; even if all the moderators asked for a tag to be blacklisted, it probably wouldn't happen.

Answer (score 2):

Making a tag synonym of another one is made when strictly necessary, which means there are users who keep using the wrong tag that is synonym of another tag. In your case, [v7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/v7) could be considered a synonym of [7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7), and it would be made a synonym of that tag if editing questions would not be enough to remove the tag from the existing questions because for each edited questions there are X new questions using the wrong tag.
It is also done to keep the tags from migrated questions, since a migrated question keeps those tags that are defined in the site receiving the question. That is why [drupal-views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-views) is a synonym of [views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views).
In other cases, the synonym is created when there are already X questions using that tag, which has been a bad choice since the beginning, and we then decide to use another one.

As for blacklisting, that is something only a Stack Exchange Community Coordinator can do; for that reason, blacklisting is not something normally done. It is also done when there is the certainty the tag will never be used.

The other possibility is burninating a tag, which means removing it from every revision of every post using it. At the end, it would be like if the tag was never used from any question. Also in this case, since it is something done from a Community Coordinator, they do it when there is a clear consensus from the community; they don't do it because two moderators ask for that.